Delete command is not working for List View in .NET MAUI
Somehow my DeleteNotificationCommand is not working, I can't figure out why? I am new to MAUI, any help would be appreciated.
The command is not even getting triggered since, it's not hitting the debug point in viewmodel constructor.
MainPage.xaml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Notis.Model"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notis.ViewModel"
             x:Class="Notis.MainPage"
             Title="Notifications">

    <RefreshView x:Name="NotisRefreshView"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="verticalStackLayout" Spacing="25" Margin="25">

                <ListView x:Name="listView"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
                          RowHeight="75"
                          SeparatorColor="Silver"
                          SelectionMode="Single">       
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="*, *" ColumnDefinitions="5*, *">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding NotificationTitle}"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="10, 0"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding NotificationText}"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="10, 0"/>        
                                    <Button Text="Del"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                            Command="{Binding DeleteNotificationCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>

</ContentPage>

ViewModel file
namespace Notis.ViewModel;

public class NotificationViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly DatabaseRepository _databaseRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<NotificationDBO> _notifications;

    public ObservableCollection<NotificationDBO> Notifications
    {
        get => _notifications;
        set => SetProperty(ref _notifications, value);
    }

    public Command<NotificationDBO> DeleteNotificationCommand { get; }
    public bool isRefreshing;
    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get => isRefreshing;
        set
        {
            isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
        }
    }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }

    public NotificationViewModel(DatabaseRepository dataRepository)
    {
        _databaseRepository = dataRepository;
        DeleteNotificationCommand = new Command<NotificationDBO>(DeleteNotification);

        LoadNotifications();

        RefreshCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            LoadNotifications();
            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }

    public async void LoadNotifications()
    {
        Notifications = new ObservableCollection<NotificationDBO>(await _databaseRepository.GetNotificationsAsync());
    }

    public async void DeleteNotification(NotificationDBO notification)
    {
        await _databaseRepository.DeleteNotificationAsync(notification.Id);
        Notifications.Remove(notification);
    }
}

MainPage.xaml.cs file
using Notis.ViewModel;

namespace Notis;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly NotificationViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage(NotificationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = viewModel;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }
}

I found this blog: https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/14852/how-to-remove-listviewitem-using-button-in-item-template-in-net-maui-listviewsflistview
and, tried adding Source and Path as following but didn't work.
<Button Text="Del"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"


You need to use a relative binding.  You’re on the right track with your last snippet, except that “DeleteCommand” should be “DeleteNotificationCommand”

My bad, tried that it worked, thanks!

Congrats. Could you please post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks for in advance. :)
